# How to sort HTML table in MVC based on value selected in dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement where I have to sort the HTML table in MVC on the basis of value selected in dropdownlist.

The dropdownlist is having 2 values: Sort by Number and Sort By Description.
Following is the code:

```
@{
    Layout = T4MVC.SharedController.ViewNames._Ctx;
}

@section brandcrambs{
    <div id="breadcrumbs">@{Html.RenderPartial(T4MVC.SharedController.ViewNames._ProductCatalogBrandCrambs, Model);}</div>
}
@Html.DropDownList("SortBy", new List<SelectListItem>
{
                    new SelectListItem{ Text="Sort By Number", Value="0", Selected=true},
                    new SelectListItem{ Text="Sort By Description", Value = "1" }
                 })
@{
    var s = @ViewData["currentNode"];
}
<div style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold">
    @Convert.ToString(s)
</div>

@foreach (SubSectionNodesVM n in Model.Nodes)
{
    <h4>

        @if (n.CurrentNode.Key.Contains("Specification"))
        {
            Html.RenderPartial(T4MVC.SharedController.ViewNames._PrintButtons, n.CurrentNode);
        }
    </h4>
        var matchValue = n.Nodes as IEnumerable<SiteMapNodeBase>;
        var resultSet = from dtRow in matchValue.AsEnumerable()
                        group dtRow by dtRow.Prefix into newGroup
                        orderby newGroup.Key
                        select newGroup;
        var datamodel = resultSet as IEnumerable<SiteMapNodeBase>;
        var k = 0;
    <div id="@n.CurrentNode.Key.Replace("Specification|", "").Replace("Section|", "")" >

        <table>


            @foreach (var item in resultSet)
            {
                k++;
                var match = item.Select(m => m.DefaultValue);

                string resultDefaultValue = string.Empty;

                if (match != null)
                {
                    if (match.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        resultDefaultValue = match.ToList()[0];
                    }
                }



                <tr style="background-color:@(k % 2 == 1 ? "white" : "rgb(246,246,246)")">
                    <td colspan="4" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold">@resultDefaultValue</td>



                </tr>

                var i = 0;
                foreach (var inneritem in item)
                {
                    k++;  
                <tr style="background-color:@(k % 2 == 1 ? "white" : "rgb(246,246,246)")">
                    <td style="width: 250px"><a href="@HUtil.UrlPrefix@Url.SiteMapUrl(inneritem)">@inneritem.Number</a></td>
                    @if (@inneritem.RangeStart == null || @inneritem.RangeStart == "")
                    {
                        <td style="width: 250px"></td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td style="width: 250px">From: @inneritem.RangeStart</td>  
                    }
                    @if (@inneritem.RangeEnd == null || @inneritem.RangeEnd == "")
                    {
                        <td style="width: 250px"></td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td style="width: 250px">To: @inneritem.RangeEnd</td>
                    }
                    <td style="width: 800px">@inneritem.Description</td>
                </tr>
                }




            }

        </table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#SortBy').change(function () {
            var value = $("#SortBy option:selected").val();
            alert(value);
        });
    })

</script>
```

Comment: That's a lot of server-side code to put in a view.  What are those var assignments and LINQ statements sort of randomly placed in the middle there?  Are those even being interpreted server-side?  Any time you need to declare new variables in a view, it's generally a sign that logic needs to be moved to the model.  As for sorting a table, that sounds like it would make a lot more sense to do in JavaScript than in server-side code.  No sense posting back a form just to get the same data again in a different sort order.  There are tons of JavaScript table plugins that can sort rows.

Comment: Yes David. I completely agree with you about server side code being used in View and that will be removed. As for sorting we cannot use any Javascript plugins. Is there a way I can use jquery and use the above code only?

Comment: You can't use JavaScript libraries, but you can use jQuery?  Those two statements are mutually exclusive.  In any event, if you can't use a library which does something for you then the alternative is to write the code which does it yourself.  I've personally never written a table sorter before (since there are *so many* ready-made solutions for it already), and I imagine there are a number of ways to approach it.  It's certainly a larger scope than a single Stack Overflow question though.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you read this article:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

It will explain how to sort (and filter etc) data from Entity Framework based on input. The sample does not use a Dropdown to demonstrate this, but if you understand the sample, you should be able to get it to work with a DropDown.

This is a **server side** approach, which I would always recommend when it comes to searching, sorting and paging.

If you chose to sort things on the client side, then it requires a different approach. There are many plugins for it, you can also do it yourself with pure javascript, or jQuery

Examples for **client side** sorting plugins:

- https://datatables.net/
- http://tablesorter.com/
- http://joequery.github.io/Stupid-Table-Plugin/
- ...